# How Page class's property(instance) is accessible without object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

This might be a silly question, but i have a confusion. 
Every `.aspx` page inherits  `System.Web.UI.Page` and [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class has some properties Like, `IsPostBack`, `IsValid`,`IsCrossPagePostBack` and many more... to access these property we write `Page.IsPostBack` or `IsPostBack`. 
Now, Question is , are these property `static` , if not then how these are accessible in the `.apsx` file, i have tried to test with a `class` but not succeeded.

```
    public class clsDemo:System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page class derives from `TemplateControl` class;

```
public class Page : TemplateControl, IHttpHandler
```

and `TemplateControl` class derives from abstract `Control` class;

```
public abstract class TemplateControl : Control, ...
```

In `Control` class which `Page` class derives from there is a virtual property named as Page;

```
    // Summary:
    //     Gets a reference to the System.Web.UI.Page instance that contains the server
    //     control.
    //
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }
```

In the `Page` class there are properties like `IsPostBack`, `IsValid` etc;

```
    // Summary:
    //     Gets a value that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the first
    //     time or is being loaded in response to a postback.
    //        
    public bool IsPostBack { get; }
```

Thus,

Since the aspx page derives from `Page` class, it also inherits `TemplateControl` and `Control` classes. In `Control` class there is a public property named as `Page` thus you can access `Page` property in your class. And `Page` class has public properties like `IsPostback` and `IsValid` etc., so you can use these properties from `Page` property.

```
public class Test : Page
{
    public Test()
    {
        bool test = this.IsCallback;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain in detail ,how it getting called, or have to access these property in a class

Comment: @ daryal, how to access these property in a class.

Comment: @Arshad in what class, a class deriving from Page?

Comment: its not working at all, i have tried, added also in the question(last part)

Comment: @Arshad I have added a class and derived it from Page, I can access IsCallback, IsPostBack etc; maybe I did not understand the problem properly.

Comment: i am creating a single class file and inheriting it from System.Web.UI.Page. but not a single property is coming

Comment: @Arshad I have done exactly what you have stated and it works properly; what is you project type?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23830/discussion-between-arshad-and-daryal)